# How do I disable redirect to login page for ASP NET application

Tags: asp.net

As a new person, who decided to write a web page - I ran into the problem: I have a page, which I want to be set up as a default page, but whenever I type my site name - it always redirects me to a ~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F page. Since my site is a private one without hosting, I want it to redirect directly to a page with a content.
Can someone tell me how do I do that?

Site was created using Visual Studio community, ASP .NET application (.NET Framework)

Comment: Check your web.config file and look for an element called `authentication`and change the `mode` attribute to `None`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's already set to none

Comment: Could you please provide us the steps which you have followed while creating your project?

Comment: New project -> Web -> ASP .NET Web Application (.NET Framework) -> Single Page Application

Comment: Remove the [Authorize] attribute from your HomeController and remove this below code from your  index.cshtml. You can follow these steps in whichever pages you want to skip authentication. Just go to that particular controller page and remove [Autherize] attribute. and below script from that particular ->
     .cshtml                                                                   
 @section Scripts{
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}